# caller arguments for Flash object which runs JS

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

We have many flash banners which we don't control (we can't change their source code to pass parameters).
They run a single JS when clicked. This script is on our side, sits on the same domain as the banners.
We wonder how can we find from inside the JS any arguments regarding the calling Flash object, for example, the file name of the SWF, it's position on the page etc.

We tried using arguments.callee.caller in JS but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If the SWF doesn't pass any of theses informations as arguments, you just **can't** figure out which SWF called your javascript function.

You can maybe get stack traces in JS, but they will be the same regardless of the callee SWF.

Comment: It refers to the javascript function who called your function, not to the object which processed it.

Answer (score 0):

You might work around this by creating a common holder swf that loads in a banner and handle clicks from that swf, ignoring the javascript calls from the original banner. You could pass in a flashvar to distinguish between the different banners and pass any info to the js function.